How to determine what causes a SSL handshake failure
Update: PCAP file: https://fastupload.io/0362cd55628fb281
I have an application built in 2017 that uses OpenSSL 1.0.1h (file named ssleay32.dll). I have a new version of this application that uses a recent (within the last year) version of curl instead. The old application gets a handshake failure error when trying to connect to a particular server, hazards.fema.gov. I read that the most common cause is the client and server being unable to find a common cipher suite. However, I traced with WireShark and it appears that shouldn't be the cause. In particular, whether connecting with the old program or the new program, TLSv1.2 is used. The server says (according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hazards.fema.gov) it accepts two cipher suites:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (preferred)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

The new program offers 16 suites, including the two listed above, and the server chooses the preferred TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and the handshake works.
The old program offers 18 suites, including the non-preferred one above, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, and the handshake fails.
So, assuming the problem is not an inability to find a common cipher suite, I'm wondering how I can figure out what is causing the handshake failure. (I do not have access to the server.)
Additional information is that both the old and new programs can connect successfully to another https server (cameo.noaa.gov). In this case the old program offers 78 cipher suites, and the server chooses TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, whereas the new program offers 18 suites and the server again chooses TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
Both servers offer only TLSv1.2. Both clients are thus able to speak TLSv1.2.
Is there a chance that even though the hazards.fema.gov server says it accepts two cipher suites it actually only accepts the preferred one?
If not, is there any way to get more information on why the handshake fails?

Update: Handshake extension information
Failure in old application:
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
Length: 164
Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
Random: 664d0a89bbdac83cd7a2f8244f6b71b6561e7b36d8b553cee79b5ae4f2916f10
Session ID Length: 0
Cipher Suites Length: 36
Cipher Suites (18 suites)
Compression Methods Length: 1
Compression Methods (1 method)
Extensions Length: 87
Extension: server_name (len=21) name=hazards.fema.gov
Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
Extension: channel_id_old (len=0)
Extension: status_request (len=5)
Extension: signature_algorithms (len=18)
<snip>

Success in new application:
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
Length: 508
Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
Random: 3f299f8cfc9675877c69d9d858d0b31f5ed6bd8ae9fdc0818bee74ec96f48629
Session ID Length: 32
Session ID: 7eb39bb9ec2e9e53a9b803c1d085ca359289fb7a6202d0b65e3015455dcbc0db
Cipher Suites Length: 32
Cipher Suites (16 suites)
Compression Methods Length: 1
Compression Methods (1 method)
Extensions Length: 403
Extension: Reserved (GREASE) (len=0)
Extension: server_name (len=21) name=hazards.fema.gov
Extension: supported_versions (len=7) TLS 1.3, TLS 1.2
Extension: status_request (len=5)
Extension: key_share (len=43) x25519
Extension: supported_groups (len=10)
Extension: signature_algorithms (len=18)
Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
Extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (len=14)
Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
Extension: application_settings (len=5)
Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
Extension: compress_certificate (len=3)
Extension: signed_certificate_timestamp (len=0)
Extension: Reserved (GREASE) (len=1)
Extension: padding (len=199)
<snip>


I would say the most common cause is a certificate issue. There are quite enough cipher suites for both peers to be able to agree. However if the server isn't equipped with a private key it can only to try to negotiate anonymous cipher suites, which are usually disabled at both ends, so you sometimes see 'no cipher suites in common' when the real problem is a misconfigured server. Your image, which should not have been posted here in this form, is illegible and therefore useless. You need to provide the actual text of the error message, and as text, not as an image.

It is probably worth comparing the contents of a working vs non-working ClientHello, paying particular attention to the extensions. One that springs to mind is that OpenSSL 1.0.1h does not support extended-master-secret, but more recent versions do. It is plausible that the server requires it.

Please provide the actual pcap file for the connection, not just a screendump. No details about the ClientHello can be seen there, but it is relevant since the server obviously does not like the ClientHello.

@SteffenUllrich, PCAP file link added

@MattCaswell, thanks. I have added extension information to the bottom of the post. Indeed the new application includes many additional extensions, including extended_master_secret (although its length is 0). So now I'll try to figure out which (if any) of those additional extensions is required by the server. Is there a faster way than process of elimination? Or actually, I see that the server sends a list of (presumably required) extensions in its Hello message. And indeed extended_master_secret is among them, as is renegotiation_info, which is non-0 length and the more likely culprit.

@MattCaswell, if you want to copy your comment as an answer, I'll select it.

First, empty data for extdmaster is correct; see RFC 7627. Something is weird here; I have an archived system with 1.0.1h and its s_client connects okay to that host with either ECDHE-RSA-AES{128,256}-GCM-SHA{256,384}, without extdmaster, with or without servername, and with or without statusreq. But it uses the 5746 SCSV (ERI) not extension, and sends servername, pointfmt len=4, suppcurves len=52. ticket, sigalgs len=32, [status], heartbeat -- like your frame 4, the successful request to noaa. ...

... Turning off heartbeat makes sense for a 2017 timeframe, but I've never seen an OpenSSL that varies order of (nonomitted) extensions within a protocol version, or has anything called 'channel_id_old' (which I've never heard of), or has any support for reneginfo rather than ERI on initial request -- but note when reneginfo is used, len=1 IS correct, see RFC 5746. Are you quite sure the program is using OpenSSL for the problem (fema) connection, not something else like curl-with-NSS or schannel (given Windows)? Also ServerHello contains the extensions the server accepted.

@dave_thompson_085 thanks for the research. And I think, D'oh!, you are probably right that the 2017 program is not actually using that 1.0.1h DLL, and rather is using Chromium Embedded Framework, based on a version of Chromium that might be older than 2017. I'll try to research what that version of CEF is using internally.

@dave_thompson_085 however, I'm trying to understand if my overall conclusion is still correct. When the new program connects to fema, I see the server hello lists ec_point_formats, renegotiation_info, extended_master_secret, and application_layer_protocol_negotiation (all of which are sent by the new client, and the first two of which are sent by the old client). You say these are what the server accepted. But is it likely that means these are also what the server requires, so it explains the likely reason for the failure (regardless of what library the client is using)?

@dave_thompson_085 this is the November 2017 version of Chromium that the old client's CEF was built on: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/63.0.3239.61

@dave_thompson_085 I saw one source that said Chromium 63.0.3239 likely used OpenSSL, but at least in 2010 this said it uses NSS: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/foL_FKOvXC8?pli=1

(1) Since 2015 Chrome/ium uses BoringSSL which is based on OpenSSL but heavily modified. (2) just because a server accepts an extension offered by the client doesn't mean it requires it -- most extensions are/were designed to be optional, and for extdmaster on this host my testing confirms it is. reneginfo is kind of special -- client can request it either by sending the extension (with len=1) OR by sending the SCSV (Signaling CipherSuite Value), and either way the server replies with the extension. ...

... pointfmts is even more special in that it doesn't really negotiate at all, rather each side unilaterally declares what it accepts. But I'd be pretty confident if you're offering pointsfmts len=2 it contains (only) uncompressed, and if you're also offering suppcurves-aka-suppgroups len=8 that contains the 'big 3' (P256, P384, P521) -- you can check these by clicking the plus-boxes in wireshark -- and my testing confirms this server will use and in fact choose uncompressed P384 for ECDHE. I should check the certs also but that will take longer.

Oops -- it won't take long; of course the certs are (all) RSA!

@dave_thompson_085 thanks for all the effort. I wasn't quite able to tell: Can you summarize your overall opinion on the server hello failure based on what you see?

Summary: it's not extdmaster, servername(SNI), statusreq, or ticket, and probably not suppcurves or pointfmts. I doubt it's sigalgs. It shouldn't be reneginfo as an extension versus SCSV but I can't easily test, and it shouldn't be channel_id_old but I can't test. And even if it is one of those I don't see any way for you to fix it, except by putting a proxy in the middle, like squid or just socat, and for that you don't actually need to identify the problem, only find a combination that works.
